# Change app request notification text using facebook-javascript-sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi am using the following code to send app request to friends but in notification it shows the message as invited you to try test app. It is not displaying the entered message. please help

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        title   : 'Test App',
        message : 'Test app message'
    }, requestCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible issues here.

1. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) says that the maximum message length is 60 characters. Your message might be too long so it is truncated.
2. The documentation goes on to say

   > Invites (requests where the recipient has not installed the app) do not display this value.

   So this means that if this is the first `apprequest` this user has received prior to installing the application, s/he will not see the message but only the "invitation" to start using your application.

Using the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), you will be able to "predict" whether the user has installed the application or not by using the filter parameter. Set it to `app_users` to only display users who have already installed - in this case you can include the (60 character limited) message parameter. If you set the filter to `app_non_users`, you might want to include the content of your message in the title parameter as it is always shown. The title parameter is limited to 50 characters.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    title   : 'Test App',
    message : 'Test app message',
    filters : ['app_users']
}, requestCallback);
```

Which ever way you decide to go, you'll want to have a relatively short message/title for your invites/requests.

Comment: Thanks.. The notification message for authorised (displays the app name) and unathorised (invited you to try test app) but the entered message is missing(Test app message).

Comment: I don't think you'll see the message in the notification bar - only in the [App center requests](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests) tab.

Comment: ok thank you. But how can i show the message in notification bar is it possible?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do that, sorry.